# Do all players spawn on the same block in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do all players on server spawn at the exactly same spot?

What I mean is, do *all* the players have the **exact same** spawn coordinates?

I know that the player spawns at the same point so if I place a dirt block in the place I spawned
*all* the players will spawn on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my spawn point change on my SMP server every time I respawn?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17359/why-does-my-spawn-point-change-on-my-smp-server-every-time-i-respawn)

Answer (score 12):

> In multiplayer, players will spawn, by default, anywhere within a 20x20 area centered at the spawn point. An individual player can change their spawn point by merely lying in a bed -- they do not have to go to sleep (which can only happen if all players sleep at the same time).

So the default spawn point is *kind of* the same.  There is a large amount of info on [multiplayer spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn/Multiplayer_Details).

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Sorry, but in SMP the server picks a random block from the spawn chunk to spawn people.  They don't spawn on the same block every time.

Comment: Why did this receive a down vote?

Answer (score 0):

Players will spawn on different blocks every time in Vanilla Minecraft, but it is possible to use a server mod such as Bukkit to set an exact spawn point.

Answer (score 0):

In a vanilla SMP Mine-Craft server, blocks are randomly chosen at a certain hight limit.

Answer (score 0):

**Usually not**, but as of [release 1.3.1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.3.1), the answer is a little more complicated.

If the player that is playing is in [survival](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Survival) or [creative](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creative) mode, the game will randomly pick a X and Z coordinate within a 10x10* area of the spawn location, and spawn them at the highest block on that coordinate (note: if there are no blocks at the location, the player will fall into The Void).

There are a few cases where this does not apply.

## Adventure Mode

In [adventure mode](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Adventure), the player always spawns at the specified location, except if the user has a specific spawn point (more on that later). Barring this, they will always spawn on the specific block.

## Beds

Using a [bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed) will set your spawn location to a "safe" location around the bed, although this will reset to the world spawn area if you destroy it.

## /spawnpoint Operator Command

In [release 1.4.2](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.4.2), the [/spawnpoint command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#spawnpoint) was added to the vanilla game. This command allows operators to set the spawn of a particular user.

Unlike beds, this ignores any safety check, and will spawn players in a block if there happens to be one at the location.

## The `spawnRadius` game rule

This is the number of blocks out that a player can randomly spawn at. If this is set to 0, then users will spawn on the same block every time they respawn (unless a user's custom spawn point applies).

* As of Minecraft 1.10. I do not know if it the same in older versions of Minecraft. It appears that at some point multiplayer and singleplayer did have a different spawn radius, according to the wiki.